# What are the different types of shrines and their effects in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

So far I've noticed a shrine that offers a speed increase, gold find and magic find increase, and damage reduction. What are the other types and their effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my personal experience, there are four types of shrines that I can confirm:

- Shrine of Enlightenment - +25% Experience.
- Shrine of Fortune - +25% Magic and Gold Find.
- Shrine of Protection - Reduces damage taken by 25%.
- Shrine of Frenzy (Not sure if that is the real name) - Increases attack speed by 25%.

Comment: I just tested with a frenzy shrine and it did not increase my crit damage

Comment: That was patched out a couple of patches ago (this answer is from just two days after release). I'll edit it in :)